# internal server error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, internal-server-error

When running a project in Codeigniter, error appears like this:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `.htaccess` file, remove it and try again.